# keyboard height issue on rotation in message composer view

Tags: ios, rotation, keyboard, xcode7

I am using message composer view for creating messages in my app..on click of button this message composer view opens with keyboard...when i click on button for opening message composer view in both orientations,it is always correctly on the top of keyboard but when i open composer view in one orientation & rotate in other orientation,keyboard height doesn't change & composer view gets detached from top of keyboard. How can I get different keyboard height value on rotation?

**I am using following code for keyboard height**

```
(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    keyboardAnimationDuration = [[notification userInfo][UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];

       NSLog(@".... KB all Notifs ......");

    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    //... NSLog(@"keyboard size: W %f   and  H:%f",kbSize.width,kbSize.height);

    keyboardHeight = kbSize.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe for `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` notification and change frames there.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: thanks, it worked...but in landscape mode my text view is just detaching from keyboard..how to make text view stick to keyboard in landscape mode also?